# Update column with current sysdate and keep both records(updated and old)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a table by name **temp** with columns as

```
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(4000)
 CREATED_DATE                                       DATE
 MODIFIED_DATE                                      DATE
 IS_ACTIVE                                          NUMBER
```

I'm storing record into a table with default sysdate in CREATED_DATE column and IS_ACTIVE column to 1.so I need to update a record which should reflect MODIFIED_DATE column to current sysdate and IS_ACTIVE to 1,but(should keep old record with IS_ACTIVE 0).

Comment: If you have a table with `varchar2`, then you are using Oracle, not MySQL.  I changed the tag.

Comment: What is the logic behind the update, and what are the values of the other columns?

Comment: like as if in NAME column I have date like "Leo" and somebody next day update the column as "Leo Messi". so I want both date should be there with different values under IS_ACTIVE column as 0 & 1 respectively for (old and new).

Comment: Google how to implement SCD2 in Oracle.

Comment: How will scd-2 work with the natural key as only one column (Name). I mean if the natural key is Name then if there is a new value of name scd-2  will not be achieved as it will consider the input as  a brand new row.